# Start new Process from Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, process, tomcat7

I've got the following problem:

I am trying to start a new Process from the current running web application
of the Tomcat Server. So the web application should be able to start a new process.
If I try this from Tomcat, nothing happens. However, if I use the same Code within a own Java Application, which is not running on Tomcat, everything works fine.

Which part did I miss? Does Tomcat not allow to start a new process from a web application?
Do I have to set a special permission?

Here the Code, which works fine within the standalone java application:

```
public class Test1 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
    String javaBin = javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator
            + "java";
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String className = Test2.class.getCanonicalName();

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-cp", classpath,
            className);

    Process process;

    try {
        process = builder.start();

         Scanner s = new
         Scanner(process.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\Z");
         System.out.println(s.next());

        process.getOutputStream().close();
        process.getErrorStream().close();
        process.getInputStream().close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The Test2.class does nothing else than printing "hello world" on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried using a library like [`MPI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) or [`OpenMP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) to manage processes? (both very reliable)

Comment: Which OS are you using? If Linux, is Selinux restrictive?

Comment: Starting a process from Tomcat sounds dubious. What do you want that process to do? Maybe there's a better way, without processes.

Comment: No, I did not used such a libary, yet. I will have a look into it. Currently, the tomcat only runs on a windows 7 vm. @PhilippReichart I have to run a very computation intensive optimization within this process and it should not block the main web service or make it much slower during its general work.

Comment: Is that computation intensive optimization also a Java program? If so, I'd suggest to run it asynchronously using an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) or go with the JMS approach mentioned below by Philippe Bossu. The "proper" way would probably involve EJBs, as playing around with threads/executors in a Servlet environment is also dubious (but less so than spawning processes).

Comment: Yes, it is also a java application. I will have a look at the "proper" way with JMS, but also I will have a small look at executors. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue certainly comes from different classpath content at least.

But I agree what you are trying to do is not clean.

Why not use JMS to post the job in a queue and have another MDB process it ?